# How to add a className "row" only once inside a .map function to wrap/nest articles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a class "row" inside a .map function but only once, only if the current article boolean is equal to true.

Before the article, I would like to add a class "row" but only once. So, that I can be able to nest my grid columns.

```
import React from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const BlogColumns = review => {
    return review.primary
        ? 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6'
        : 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3';
};

const BlogReviews = ({ reviews }) => (
    <section id="latest-blogs" className="blog--bg">
        <div className="row">
            <h3 className="section__title">Latest reviews</h3>
            {reviews.map(review => (
                <div key={review.date} className={BlogColumns(review)}>
                    <article className="blog">
                        <div
                            className="blog__image"
                            style={{
                                backgroundImage: `url(${review.image})`,
                            }}
                        />
                        <div className="blog__content">
                            <h4 className="blog__title">{review.title}</h4>

                            <span className="blog__category">
                                {review.category} /{' '}
                                <time className="blog__time">
                                    {review.date}
                                </time>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </section>
);

BlogReviews.propTypes = {
    reviews: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default BlogReviews;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just about composition more than anything, if you move the review rendering into its own component e.g.

```
const BlogReviewItem = ({ review }) => (
  <article className="blog">
    <div
      className="blog__image"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${review.image})`,
      }}
    />
    <div className="blog__content">
      <h4 className="blog__title">{review.title}</h4>
      <span className="blog__category">
        {review.category} /{' '}
        <time className="blog__time">
          {review.date}
        </time>
      </span>
    </div>
  </article>
);
```

Then you can easier conditionally wrap the primary item

```
{reviews.map(review => (
  <div key={review.date} className={BlogColumns(review)}>
    {review.primary ? 
       <div className="row"><BlogReviewItem review={review} /></div> : 
       <BlogReviewItem review={review} />
    }
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Very smart one great tip. Thanks this will help me for sure in the future.

Comment: @Galanthus no problem, you could go a step further and even have a `BlogReviewPrimaryItem` component if the primary gets a bit more complex :)

Comment: Yes, agree will do to even make it more complex and elegant looking. Thanks!